# How to create a Marine Monster?

Tags: monsters, anima-beyond-fantasy

By Marine Monster I mean a creature which lives in water, such as The Kraken.

There's no marine monster (that I could find) in any manual.

Also I found that there are not enough options in the Powers of Creatures to let me create one.

Trying to do so with the options available I came up with the following problems:

- Aquatic movement lets the creature swim without problems, but I'd need to aknowledge the impedment to walk on land.
- No option of needing water to breathe, though there exist the option to not needing breathing.
- No option of ignoring any penalizer when in water. I can assume that Aquatic movement does that, but it's not clear.

Taking that into account, how should one create a Marine Monster? How should one use or adapt the existing creature powers to represent the abilities an aquatic monster has?

Comment: Anima's monster creation rules do have a few holes, unfortunately. There's no way to make a monster not age other than giving them the spell that suppresses aging, for instance. It *might* be the case that you'll have to house-rule some of this stuff... But I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, the Anima books are lacking in creatures and creature options.

Still, there are ways around if you want to stick to RaW (I don't recommend that option, since RaW has some issues in Anima). Here goes:

- > Aquatic movement lets the creature swim without problems, but I'd need to aknowledge the impedment to walk on land.

  Don't go with aquatic movement, then. Using Mystical Flight Value, you can specify conditions. Putting Conditional Flight: Underwater would limit the creature to do so in the water. The basic movement value (which can be as low as you want) can be used on land.
- > No option of needing water to breathe, though there exist the option to not needing breathing.

  This is exactly what Extreme Vulnerability is for. Whether Generic Material: Air, Unfiltered Sun or Moonlight, Wind or even Specific Place: Not Underwater. You can also decide how much impact it has with the Various consequences.
- > No option of ignoring any penalizer when in water. I can assume that Aquatic movement does that, but it's not clear.

  The only named penalty in water is to movement, and Aquatic Movement does that. Your creature doesn't need more in that case.

There are, unfortunately, no good examples of Aquatic creature. The Balzak (Those Who Walked Among Us p.23) come the closest, but they aren't restricted to underwater.